# Get sublist of n elements from unique permutations of a list

Tags: python, unique, permutation, dice

I'm writing code to roll dice with different numbers of sides together. The main function takes in a list of 2 numbers which represent the number of sides the dice have, e.g. `[4, 6]` — meaning the program will do things with a `d4` and a `d6`.

Here's the problem:

I have a list of all the different types of dice to use `[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]` and I need some code to figure out every unique group of 2 dice to pass in, without passing in the same dice in a different order, e.g.: don't pass in both `[4, 6]` and `[6, 4]`.

I plan to expand the program in the future to roll `n` dice at a time, e.g. `5d4` and `2d20` so code that doesn't only work for 2 dice would be greatly appreciated.

Lastly, I want to be able to roll 2 of the same dice, e.g.: `[4, 4]`.

If the problem needs more explaining, please let me know.

Comment: `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(dice, 2)`

Comment: I think that should be `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to allow `[4, 4]` and similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `combinations_with_replacements` from `itertools` library.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

dice = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]
N_dice = 2

print(list(combinations_with_replacement(dice, N_dice)))
```

Gives output

```
[(4, 4), (4, 6), (4, 8), (4, 10), (4, 12), (4, 20), (6, 6), (6, 8), (6, 10), (6, 12), (6, 20), (8, 8), (8, 10), (8, 12), (8, 20), (10, 10), (10, 12), (10, 20), (12, 12), (12, 20), (20, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `d20` package does this. See https://pypi.org/project/d20/.

Here is an example of its use:

```
d20.roll("1d12+3d8+4d6+14").total
```